# how to pipe a page after page in node?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to create one stream of data, pipe it to the page and end it.
Then I want to create another stream and pipe that data onto the same page.
Here is the code:

```
const express = require("express");  
const fs = require("fs");  
const body_parser = require("body-parser");  


//create an instance of the express module  
const app = express();  

app.use(body_parser())  

app.get("/open", function(req,res){  

    var stream = fs.createReadStream("./files/something.html").pipe(res);  
    var stream2 = fs.createReadStream("./files/something2.html").pipe(res);  

})



app.listen(8080,function(){
    console.log("The server has run correctly")
})
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the option `{end: false}` to the first `.pipe()` that tells it not to close the stream you're piping to.

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream("./files/something.html").pipe(res, {end:false});  
var stream2 = fs.createReadStream("./files/something2.html").pipe(res);
```

That option is described [here in the doc](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options).

Note: this code needs proper error handling.